# Construct relationship in models in rails and Insert data into it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, relationship

How to construct a model in rails 3

1. user having one profile.
2. user having one notification
3. user having one role such as admin etc.

I want to make their relation ship.
After making it.

**How to use one form to insert data into all these tables at a time.**

Any help will be appriciated..
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html to better understand rails associations.

**user.rb**

```
has_one :profile
has_one :notification
has_one :role

accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, :notification, :role
```

You might to put each of the "accepts nested attributes for" on their own line.

The each other model would need:

> belongs_to :user

**EDIT**

**form**

```
= form_for @user do |f|

 .field
   f.text_field :name

 .field
   f.text_field :email

 f.fields_for :profile do |t|
   .field
     t.text_field :description

 .actions
   = f.submit
```

Also, in your controller, make sure to have:

```
def new
 @user = User.new(profile: Profile.new)
end
```

Comment: But i am not able to insert the data  from the single form into all these three tables

Comment: For this you have to use [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

Answer (score -1):

go through rails [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) and some tutorial may be [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)